# Repeated background SVG showing white lines on Safari/iOS

Tags: html, css, ios, svg, background-image

I made a svg pattern from flaticon's pattern generator and set background repeat to true. The bg works alright on android, but on iOS (I tried it on iOS Firefox and safari) repeated lines are being drawn across the image (meaning there are gaps between them).

Here's what I mean, first image is the expected behavior and the second one is from iOS. Any pointers on how to fix this would help a ton, thanks.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcnH8.jpg

Comment: You can include images in your question with ``![](imgurl)`` You can do a lot of Markdown styling; the better your question, the more likely you get good answers: [Take the StackOverflow Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Can we see your code with the SVG. Otherwise we will just be guessing.